# use & symbol in an xml feed

Tags: xml

Please take a look at this feed: http://www.yourbestdeals.com/feeds/rss.aspx?r=test&citygroup=Boston

If you looks at the source code all the `&` symbols are actually `&amp;`. 
However, I need the symbols in the link tag to just be & otherwise they don't work in my system.

The problem is when I change these symbols to `&` the xml feed becomes invalid as `&` symbols are not a valid xml format.

Is there any way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since `&amp;` means `&` in XML (as opposed to `&` which means `start of character reference`), the XML is fine.

If it "doesn't work in your system" then you need to fix something else. The best guess I have is that something consuming the XML is not doing so using an XML parser (perhaps it is trying to parse XML with regular expressions, or perhaps you are copy/pasting the XML encoded URIs from the source).

Fix that instead of trying to hack the data.

Comment: Correct answer. If you process the XML using an XML parser, the &amp; references will automatically be delivered to the application as "&". You will only have problems if you try to hand-cut your own XML parser, which is always a really bad mistake.

Answer (score 0):

`&amp;` is the entity for ampersand, try replacing all & to `&amp;`